# When is a Haskell thread joined?

Tags: c++, multithreading, haskell

As a former C++ programmer, the behaviour of Haskell threads is confusing. Refer to the following Haskell code snippet:

```hs
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Data.Functor.Compose
import System.Random

randomTill0 :: MVar () -> IO () -- Roll a die until 0 comes
randomTill0 mV = do
    x <- randomRIO (0,65535) :: IO Int
    if 0 == x
        then putMVar mV ()
        else randomTill0 mV

main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- getNumCapabilities
    mV <- newEmptyMVar
    sequence (replicate n (forkIO (randomTill0 mV)))
    readMVar mV
    putStrLn "Excution complete."
```

As far as I know, Haskell's `forkIO` is roughly equivalent to C++'s `std::async`. In C++, I store a `std::future` which is returned by `std::async`, then `std::future::wait` for it, then the thread will be `std::thread::join`ed.

(Regarding the tiny delay before the message, I don't think any laziness is involved here.)

My question is:

1. In the above Haskell code snippet, when are the threads resulting from `forkIO`s joined? Is it upon `readMVar mV`, or the end of `main`?
2. Is there a Haskell equivalent of `std::thread::detach`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I understand, threads are never joined, and the program ends when `main` ends.  This is special to `main` –– in general threads are not associated to each other in any kind of hierarchy.    The concept of joining a thread does not exist: a thread runs until its action is finished or until it is explicitly killed with `killThread`, and then it evaporates (thanks, garbage collector).  If you want to wait for a thread to complete you have to do it yourself, probably with an `MVar`.

It follows that there is no analogue of `detach` –– all threads are automatically detached.

Another thing worth mentioning is that there is not a 1:1 correspondence between OS threads and Haskell threads.  The Haskell runtime system has its own scheduler that can run multiple Haskell threads on a single OS thread; and in general a Haskell thread will bounce around between different OS threads over the course of its lifetime.  There is a concept of [bound threads](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#g:8) which are tied to an OS thread, but really the only reason to use that is if you are interfacing with code in other languages that distinguishes between OS threads.